# How to disable days in Odoo Datepicker before a date?

Tags: python, odoo

I have a model in odoo with a fields.Date attribute (expiration_date) How can I disable all days in its odoo datepicker before a date (like january 2016), so all those days before january 2016 would not be accesible in odoo datepicker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the `minDate` option of the date picker widget.

To disable dates before `January 2016` we can pass the date as a string:

```
<field name="date_invoice" 
       options="{'datepicker': {'warn_future': true, 'minDate': '2016-01-01'}}"/>
```