# How can I define constraints for a date field in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo

I have a model in odoo with a fields.Date attribute (expiration_date). How can I add a constraint to that field to check that any date entered by the user must be after a sertain date (like january 2016)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable days in Odoo Datepicker before a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61513449/how-to-disable-days-in-odoo-datepicker-before-a-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use user defined constraint to achieve this.
Suppose, that certain date is **Today**.

```
@api.constrains('expiration_date')
def _check_expiration_date(self):
    if self.expiration_date <= datetime.today():
        raise ValidationError('Expiration date must be after today.')
```